# Show a hidden div on page load

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I have a tr like this in my jsp.

```
<tr id = "fromDate" style="display:none;">
```

I also have a select like this.

```
    <select id="select2" name="dateRange1" 
               onChange="javascript:chooseDate(this.value);">
    <option value="0" <c:if test='${dateRange == 0}'> 
            selected </c:if>>Select a Date</option>
```

The javascript function used in the select is as below.

```
function chooseDate(val) {
        if (val == "0") { 
            document.getElementById("fromDate").style.display='';
            }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("fromDate").style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

So if the selected row is not 0, i wont be displaying the tr in the page. This is working fine.
I set the dateRange variable in request.setAttribute() and sending it from action.
The problem is the option is selected properly from the request value, but the tr is not shown
I tried running it like this outside the form in jsp, hoping that it will get executed before the page load, but didn't happen.

```
<script language="javascript">
   chooseDate(${dateRange});
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What this line of javascript is doing

chooseDate(${dateRange});

Comment: My intention was to execute the chooseDate function with the dateRange request parameter on page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
<script language="javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
      chooseDate(${dateRange});
   }
</script>
```